# MYSQL multiplying result when sum, count and group

Tags: mysql

I think i need some help with this. Tried different queries million times now but nothing is working. I want it to sum t1.a and count t2.b and show the result but it is multiplying both.

I have tried left joins, right joins, without joins but i think i have not the skills to solve this!

```
$query ="SELECT t1.date, t1.a, t2.date, t2.b,
     SUM(t1.a) AS sum1,
     COUNT(t2.b) AS sum2
     FROM t1
     LEFT JOIN t2
     ON t1.date = t2.date
     GROUP BY t1.date, t2.date
     ";
```

t1:

```
id date        a
1  2019-05-01  5
2  2019-05-01  5
3  2019-05-01  5
4  2019-05-01  1
5  2019-05-01  1
6  2019-05-02  5
7  2019-05-02  5
8  2019-05-02  5
```

t2:

```
id date        b
1  2019-05-01  d
2  2019-05-01  d
3  2019-05-01  d
4  2019-05-02  d
5  2019-05-02  d
6  2019-05-02  d
7  2019-05-02  d
8  2019-05-02  d
```

The result is:

```
2019-05-01  51  15
2019-05-02  75  15
```

But it should be:

```
2019-05-01  17  3
2019-05-02  15  5
```

What i´m doing wrong???

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Zhorov :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your expected results, you must group each table first and then join them:

```
SELECT 
  t1.date, t1.sum1, t2.sum2
FROM (
  SELECT t1.date, SUM(t1.a) AS sum1
  FROM t1 GROUP BY t1.date
) t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t2.date, COUNT(t2.b) AS sum2
  FROM t2 GROUP BY t2.date
) t2
ON t1.date = t2.date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b3LMueCBRN9fzMbyU22yeU/0).
Results:

```
| date       | sum1 | sum2 |
| ---------- | ---- | ---- |
| 2019-05-01 | 17   | 3    |
| 2019-05-02 | 15   | 5    |
```

Comment: I don´t get any results at all

Comment: Yes, it seems to work but when i echo date, sum1 and sum2 in my table it cant find any results. Maybe something wrong with the rest of my code then.

Comment: I don't know if the names of tables and columns, or the data itself are the same as your actual data. Check if you adjusted the code correctly.

Comment: The code is the same i posted, i posted a image of the rest of my code now, i´m not so good at this but trying to learn

Comment: The sql code that you have is the same as mine, so it produces the same results. For the rest of the code I can't tell. This is a php problem I guess.